# Dynamically Add and Remove Case Tasks Based on changes to composition of Case Team Members

Tags: tasks, case-teams

Our cases generate a large number of tasks based on values in custom fields.  A task is created for each case team member.

The case team members assigned to our cases change fairly often.

We want to be able to dynamically delete tasks assigned to case team members when they are removed as case team members, and create new tasks based on existing tasks when new case team members are added to a case.

However, there are no triggers on case team members, so we cannot directly implement this.

Are there other approaches other then brute force:

- a scheduled query that runs through all cases and case tasks, looking to see

  - (a) if a case task is assigned to a user who is no longer a case team member and deleting those tasks, and
  - (b) looking to see if there are tasks not assigned to a current case team member and creating those tasks?

Comment: Other than a poll with a query, you can roll your own UI (component) to manage the change.